# Strange issue with merge sort, quick sort, and structs in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

While doing my C programming exercises, I've encountered this strange issue:
merge sort and quick sort algorithms loop infinitely through my array of structs, trying to sort it. 
Now, there is a third sorting algorithm available: insertion sort. With this, the sorting works fine. 
So, I tested all 3 algorithms before doing this exercise, and they work fine (tried with int, double, strings and array of strings...).
I have no idea about that... Any suggestion?
This is the code of merge sort:

```
void upo_merge_sort(void *base, size_t n, size_t size, upo_sort_comparator_t cmp)
{
    assert(base != NULL);
    
    upo_merge_sort_rec(base, 0, n-1, size, cmp);
}

void upo_merge_sort_rec(void *base, size_t lo, size_t hi, size_t size, upo_sort_comparator_t cmp)
{
    if(lo >= hi) { return; }
    
    size_t mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
    
    upo_merge_sort_rec(base, 0, mid, size, cmp);
    upo_merge_sort_rec(base, mid+1, hi, size, cmp);
    upo_merge_sort_merge(base, lo, mid, hi, size, cmp);
}

void upo_merge_sort_merge(void *base, size_t lo, size_t mid, size_t hi, size_t size, upo_sort_comparator_t cmp)
{
    unsigned char *ptr = base;
    unsigned char *aux = NULL;
    size_t n = hi - lo + 1;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = mid + 1 - lo;
    size_t k;
    
    aux = malloc(n*size);
    if(aux == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to allocate memory for auxiliary vector");
        abort();
    }
    
    memcpy(aux, ptr+lo*size, n*size);
    
    for(k = lo; k <= hi; ++k) {
        if(i > (mid - lo)) {
            memcpy(ptr+k*size, aux+j*size, size);
            ++j;
        }
        else if(j > (hi - lo)) {
            memcpy(ptr+k*size, aux+i*size, size);
            ++i;
        }
        else if(cmp(aux+j*size, aux+i*size) < 0) {
            memcpy(ptr+k*size, aux+j*size, size);
            ++j;
        }
        else {
            memcpy(ptr+k*size, aux+i*size, size);
            ++i;
        }
    }
    
    free(aux);
}
```

and compare functions:

```
int by_track_number_comparator(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const entry_t *aa = a;
    const entry_t *bb = b;
    int diff = aa->track_num - bb->track_num;
    
    return diff;
}

int by_track_title_comparator(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const entry_t *aa = a;
    const entry_t *bb = b;
    
    return strcmp(aa->track_title, bb->track_title);
}
```

entry_t is a struct type.

Comment: Try to produce a small failing example and than start debugging it.

Comment: Maybe you allocated very large arrays on the stack? It would seem that you have some icky recursive versions of quick sort and merge sort. These too will slaughter the stack, since at least this merge sort can't get tail call optimized. Solution: never declare large amounts of data on the stack and never use recursion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I can't spot the actual data allocation. And also, never use recursion is excellent advise, since some 95% of all uses of recursion in C are slow, dangerous, unreadable, memory-inefficient and bad in pretty much every possible way. There are a few very rare corner cases where tail-call optimized recursion might be suitable in order to save a bit of memory from a certain data set, but that's about the only valid use of recursion I've ever seen.

Comment: The error is on this line: `upo_merge_sort_rec(base, 0, mid, size, cmp);` It is using the wrong lower bound.

Comment: @Lundin Not every code needs to be perfectly optimised, sometimes having something clean and concise is better than an unreadable optimised code. Take into account that eldrim clearly stated that it was for an exercise, I doubt they can choose to go without recursion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The point is that it _shouldn't_ be calling a function (or rather _n_ functions) to begin with, it should be inlined into a loop or all the recursion achieved was massive overhead. Each function call comes with the stack building up without control, often resulting in stack overflow crashes. The alternative is manual unrolling into a fast, readable loop, or if you are very lucky, the compiler manages to inline it if it's tail-call. It's very hard to come up with any situation where you want slow code just for the sake of it.

Comment: @AloisChristen Yes all students are taught recursion so that they will use it in practice and create broken inefficient programs. Then later when they become teachers they will teach the next generation to use it too. But nobody actually knows what machine code it generates. The main use-case for it is posing and writing inefficient search algorithms instead of efficient ones - it's a pox. Prove me wrong by linking one single SO example where the recursion is tail-call, is more efficient than a loop, doesn't result in stack peak allocation and also improves readability.

Comment: I'm testing, again. With "large" amount of elements (40 random elements takes 30 seconds to be ordered) is very slow... Unfortunately I must use recursion, because my professor wants it... So, maybe, for sorting the array of this exercise (70 elements...) it'll take minutes

Comment: @Lundin Then what is he supposed to do ? Saying to "never use recursion" is a bad advice as it's not possible here. 
You want an example of a chimera : no recursive code is going to be all of the required things, because recursion is a trade-of : You write less efficient code and save a lot of developer's time. Recursion is fast to code, fast to understand, not efficient. It's a good trade-of for a lot a people.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because you say so? Or because you have actually troubleshooted and disassembled countless recursive functions like I have? Recursion only enables one single thing: to use the call stack as temporary store instead of storing "parent" pointers in the data container. That's it, the _only_ benefit and it's a very minor one that can only be useful in a very few scenarios. In the vast majority of use-cases, execution speed and deterministic stack usage are prioritized.

Comment: @Lundin: in real-world cases, the cost of recursion is completely absorbed in the computational load. Recursive programs are not just Fibonacci and factorials.

Comment: @YvesDaoust And that's like saying "we don't have to write efficient code because the computer is so fast anyway". I take it you haven't worked much with real-time systems. The whole point here is that we shouldn't write needlessly slow code _just for the sake of it_. Or worse, write code that's needlessly slow for the sake of posing useless language features.

Comment: @Lundin: haha, my bread and butter is code optimization. Since 40 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple error in `upo_merge_sort_rec` that makes the function recurse far deeper than it needs to. It should be sorting the elements from index `lo` to `hi` inclusive, but the lower index of one of the recursive calls is incorrectly using a fixed lower index of 0:

```
    upo_merge_sort_rec(base, 0, mid, size, cmp);
```

should be:

```
    upo_merge_sort_rec(base, lo, mid, size, cmp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice that...

Comment: @eldrim Glad that fixes it. Another possible improvement is to allocate and free the `aux` buffer (of size `n * size`) in the top level sorting function `upo_merge_sort` and pass it through to the other functions. That means you only need to call `malloc` and `free` once, rather than `n-1` times.